# wrong row height for grid pro editor

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I use vaadin 14.6.1 and the grid.
I have already made the row heights smaller / denser with the following css via @CssImport:

```css
[part~="cell"] {
    font-size: 12px;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

:host(.kalkulation-material-grid) [part="row"] {
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 20px;
}
```

The grid has a headerRow with appendHeaderRow() in which TextFields are to be displayed, which serve as filters for this column. How do I get these text fields smaller / denser. I cannot adjust the rowHeight of the headerRow.
The first line has also a wrong row height, see screenshot.

How can I adjust those row heights ?
[image]

Comment: If I have understood this question correctly, you need to customize the TextField to be smaller, so that row wont stretch height to accomodate it.

Comment: yes, that's the problem. All my CSS changes didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From Discord:

This is how the [Dense Grid Cookbook example](https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-dense-theme) does it:
`grid.setThemeName("dense");`

```
:host([theme~="dense"]) [part~="cell"] {
    min-height: var(--lumo-size-xxs);
}
:host([theme~="dense"])  {
    font-size: var(--lumo-font-size-xs);
}
:host([theme~="dense"]) [part~="cell"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
    padding: 1px var(--lumo-space-s);
}
:host([theme~="dense"]:not([theme~="no-row-borders"])) [part="row"][first] [part~="cell"]:not([part~="details-cell"]) {
     border-top: 0;
     min-height: calc(var(--lumo-size-xxs) - var(--_lumo-grid-border-width));
 }
```

There is only regular text content in that example, so the TextFields may need some additional [styling](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/styling-components).